# Cannot remove E_STRICT errors in Php 5.4

Tags: php, error-handling

I moved a server from Php 5.3 to Php 5.4

Several errors showed up which did not show using Php 5.3

I tried disabling E_STRICT errors by entering this in php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

It had no effect. The same errors kept being displayed.

I run grep -r "error_reporting" . at one website, to find if the script was setting it, but no. It was not found.

An example of an error: "illegal string offset" when checking for a key in an array.

I have many scripts on this server and it is not possible to check all the code for when an array string is used without first checking it with isset.

How can I disable those E_STRICT errors in Php 5.4 so I can keep running these older scripts without having to stick to Php 5.3 ?

Comment: At a guess you changed the wrong `php.ini` file. Look for another! You dont mention an OS so I cannot help you with where is might be

Comment: Thanks, but the server has cPanel and I changed it using WHM so it has to be the right one...

Comment: Then maybe you are going to have to wait for an Apache restart although I would of thought it would be running fastCGI but who knows

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already restarted Apache through WHM and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Illegal string offset` is a ***warning***, not an `E_STRICT` error. The code is *plain wrong*, not merely "strictly speaking sub-par". The reason you can't suppress the error is that it's a serious error which you are explicitly allowing.
2. `Illegal string offset` means you're most likely treating a string like an array, e.g.:

   ```
   $foo = 'bar';
   echo $foo['baz'];
   ```

   `'baz'` is an *illegal string offset*. A string offset is supposed to be a number. If you're using something other than a number, that a) doesn't make sense and b) is a sign that you probably expected `$foo` to be an array. So, again, plainly wrong code.

Comment: Thanks. I found it, it was a default parameter in a function and the line checking if it was an array was missing. Strange that php 5.3 did not report this error at all before.